# create a frequency matrix from a 4 dim matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix in k*4 dimension that each row is one of a combination of `(1:20,1:20,1:20,1:20)` and specify type of quadruplet node . For example for `k=3` I have 3 tetrahedron that type of node is here

```
X <- matrix(c(1,  3, 1 ,4,
              2,  5, 6 ,1,
              12,20,15 ,3),   3,4,byrow=T)
```

Now I want to create a frequency table in dim 20*8000 from it that record the frequency of each node in contact with the three remaining node. On the other hand I want to know that each node in quadruplet is in contact with which type of node.

For example for the first row I have a one in 1,(1,3,4)th of F and also in 3,(1,1,4) and in 4,(1,1,3).

I hope that I could explain my problem good to understand.
Please help me in code of this conversion

Note: 
As the first row of my X matrix is 1,3,1,4 the output matrix(F) should record a  one in the

```
F[1,which(colnames(F)=="1 3 4") <- F[1,which(colnames(F)=="1 3 4") +1
F[1,which(colnames(F)=="1 3 4") <- F[1,which(colnames(F)=="1 3 4") +1
F[3,which(colnames(F)=="1 1 4") <- F[3,which(colnames(F)=="1 1 4") +1
F[4,which(colnames(F)=="1 1 3") <- F[4,which(colnames(F)=="1 1 3")+1
```

It means that each row add 4 ones to the frequency matrix in the 4 row of it and it may be the same for 2,3 or 4 of it. For example because of one is repeated in the row one, adds two records to F[1,which(colnames(F)=="1 3 4")

Comment: So what answer is to be obtained from that first row in your example? Why does it not also include 1, (3,1,4)?  And what type of R structure should it be?

Comment: I add your request in my question, Also I should say that the output is a matrix

Comment: At the moment all the colnames are NULL. So rather than give us incorrect R code, can you instead describe what process is supposed to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand, and if I do, then you are not doing this correctly because you are not properly ordering your triplets, so this is a guess. I'm thinking the vector c(3,1,4) should be different than the vector c(1,3,4). Correct me if I'm wrong about that.

I thought trying to work with a 20^4 array was rather excessive so I constructed an input matrix that would fit in a 5^4 array:

```
X <- matrix(c(1,  3, 1 ,4,
              2,  5, 2 ,1,
              3,  2, 5 ,4),   3,4, byrow=T)
```

We produce the combinations of 4 items taken three at a time from each row and arrange it in column major fashion:

```
 array(  apply( X, 1, function(x) combn(x, 3) ), dim=c(3,4,3) )
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    3
[2,]    3    3    1    1
[3,]    1    4    4    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    2    5
[2,]    5    5    2    2
[3,]    2    1    1    1

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    3    3    2
[2,]    2    2    5    5
[3,]    5    4    4    4
```

Comment: You are right and it's different between all permutations too.

Answer (score 0):

I found an elementary answer to my question. But I think it's not quick as well as it should be.

For example I have a matrix in dim (3*4) and for simplicity I suppose I have 5 type only. 
so to find the frequncy table for this situation I write the below  codes:

```
    n <- 5
    k <- dim(X)[1]
    F <- matrix(0,n,n^3)
    colnames(F) <- simplify2array(apply(expand.grid(1:n,1:n,1:n ), 1, paste, collapse =" ", sep = ""))
    for(i in 1:k)
    {
for(j in 1:4){
per <- simplify2array(permn(X[i,-j]))
pert_charac <- apply(per,2,paste,sep="",collapse=" ")
num <- sapply(pert_charac,f <- function(x) which(colnames(F)==x))
F[X[i,j],num] <- F[X[i,j],num]+1
    }
 }
```